# What is role of Analyst in agile software development team?

Tags: agile

I want to know about "Analyst" in software development team. What is his role in development team, responsibilities, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analyst is the person responsible for accurately documenting the business requirements and turning those requirements over to the technical staff responsible for implementing them.  It's an important role because it frees the developers from having to interview the business users, so they have more time to flex their core skill (which is development).